# plt.show is not visible. How can I print to the screen(on pycharm)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pycharm

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

I tried the above code but it didn't work
No new window appears
what should I do

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
text = '''python python python python python
big data big dat big data big data big data big data big data big data big data big data
crawling crawling crawling crawling
'''

wc = WordCloud(width=1000, height=600, background_color="white")
plt.imshow(wc.generate(text))

plt.axis("off")
plt.savefig('foo.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: which version of pycharm are you using

Comment: 2020.1.1 thank you

Comment: plt.interactive(False) try to add this to your code before the plt.show

Comment: I got another error This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly. Thank you for the help

Comment: will you please state the error you got

Comment: @김경주 Can you try commenting out the line `plt.savefig('foo.png')`?